# Datetime comparison between two columns with two variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I tried to look at various online examples and couldn't get anything that relates to what I am looking for. So, I have two variables in my UDF:

```
DECLARE @XDATETYPE VARCHAR (20) = N'CUSTOMRENTRANGE',
        @XRENTSTART DATETIME,
        @XRENTEND DATETIME;
```

So if the `DateType` parameter is `'CUSTOMRENTRANGE'` then `RENTSTARTDATE` AND `RENTENDDATE` between the `@XRENTSTART` and `@XRENTEND`.

If the `DateType` parameter is `'CURRENTRENTRANGE'` then `RENTSTARTDATE` AND `RENTENDDATE` between the `@XRENTSTART` and `CurrentDateTime(GetDate())`;

What I have tried is below is not working and give me the answer I am expecting. Is there any other way to get this sorted?

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM TABLE 
    WHERE (
             (@XDATETYPE = N'CUSTOMRENTRANGE'
             AND (RENTSTARTDATE >= @XRENTSTART AND RENTENDDATE <= @XRENTEND))
             OR 
             (@XDATETYPE = N'CURRENTRENTRANGE'
             AND (RENTSTARTDATE >= @XRENTSTART AND RENTENDDATE <= GETDATE()))
          )
```

Comment: *"What I have tried is below and I am guessing this doesn't give me the answer I am expecting."* Why guess? Run it and find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider whether this reads more clearly. It might also optimize better.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE RENTSTARTDATE >= @XRENTSTART
    AND RENTENDDATE <=
        CASE @XDATETYPE
            WHEN N'CUSTOMRENTRANGE'  THEN @XRENTEND
            WHEN N'CURRENTRENTRANGE' THEN GETDATE()
        END
```

Comment: Thanks, and it's more clear. Is it possible to add the` RentStartDate` to the case statement as well? 

If the `DateType` is `N'CUSTOMRENTRANGE` or `N'CURRENTRENTRANGE` then only the whole WHERE clause is needed.

Comment: @sri A `case` is an expression that evaluates to a value. I'm not sure that I follow what you hope to accomplish. Doing it this way avoids the need to state that condition more than once.

Comment: I agree and it's working fine now. But I am trying to only use the `Where` Clause only if @`XDATETYPE = Customrentrange or Currentrentrange`. Don't need the `where` clause at all if the `@XDATETYPE` is something else.

Comment: As written, the implicit `else null` will prevent any rows matching when any other value is passed.

Answer (score 1):

Use CASE expression.

```
WHERE 
RENTSTARTDATE >= @XRENTSTART
AND
RENTENDDATE <= case @XDATETYPE 
    when 'CUSTOMRENTRANGE' then @XRENTEND 
                           else  GETDATE() end
order by ...;
```

Note I removed the difficult to read parentheses around the entire WHERE clause. That has no logical effect. Alternatively, use an IF statement to assign a variable and then simplify your query. Experiment and learn more.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to add the` RentStartDate` to the case statement as well? If the `DateType` is `N'CUSTOMRENTRANGE` or `N'CURRENTRENTRANGE` then only the whole `WHERE` clause is needed